# How can you get Animate CC to play a hosted video?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I put a video component onto the canvas and then used the code snipets to attach a video. When I use the example url that Animate CC gives in the code snippets it works (I guess because it ends with an .mp4) but when I try to put in my hosted video it doesn't work (I don't know what else to do because all of the streaming services I've used in the past (both vimeo and brightcove) give me the url of the video without .mp4 on the end. I have an embed code from the site but I don't know how to attach that to Animate's video component. Here are the two video url's below:

Vimeo's url that doesn't work with the Animate's video component:
https://vimeo.com/276593880

The url Animate CC gives in code snippets that works with the video component:
https://images-tv.adobe.com/avp/vr/15a99ccf-0e7c-4601-b270-87dd82624086/5078a43c-81f9-4a93-836c-815278b83a8e/e9cf12a0-7c4b-414f-a5c9-97ef49340aa9_20160203035417.960x540at1200_h264.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I gave up with Animate CC. I thought it'd be nice to use it's versatility alongside the video that I needed embedded into it but I couldn't find the answer so I made a simple html file and just embedded my video into that.